# ApolloClient - LazyQuery is not fired on clean-up effect

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I have a problem, I try to call a lazyQuery in a clean-up effect, and nothing happens.
When the component is unmounted, the console.log "closing connection..." is correctly printed in the console, but nothing in the Network tab of my browser.

I have checked in Insomnia that my query is correct, tested to fire the query outside of a clean-up effect, it works.
the `closeConnection` function is not undefined when the return function of the effect is called, I made sure of that too. `connectionRef.current` is not `null` nor `undefined`, because the console log in the if is printed inside the console.

`onCompleted` & `onError` are not printed in the console.
My guess is that, since it is the unmounting of the hook, the `useLazyQuery` is already unmounted when the function is called, leading to this bug where nothing happens...

I cannot find anything on this on stack overflow, and nothing in Apollo client documentation, does anybody have of had the same issue ? Any idea on how I could fix that ?

I need to call this lazyQuery when the component is unmounted, because I have a connection with my server and do not want this connection to be kept alive after the component that calls this hook is unmounted.

```
const connectionRef = React.useRef(null);
const [closeConnection] = useLazyQuery(closeConnectionQuery);

React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        if (connectionRef.current !== null) {
            console.log("closing connection ...");
            const id = connectionRef.current.id;
            connectionRef.current = null;
            closeConnection({
                variables: { id },
                onCompleted: () => {
                    console.log("ON COMPLETED");
                },
                onError: (error) => {
                    console.log("ERROR:", error);
                },
            });
        }
    };
}, []);

// connectionRef is set somewhere else in the hook, when the connection is made.
```

I expected the lazyQuery to be called properly.